# Erro no valor de parseInt do JavaScript com número muito grande

Tags: javascript

Ao converter um número em formato de string decimal para o valor numérico, recebo o número errado:

```
parseInt("36428971654192132")
// 36428971654192130
```

Answer (score 2):

De acordo com [Javascript.info](https://javascript.info/types#bigint), o tipo `number` não consegue representar corretamente números inteiros maiores que `2^53-1`, ou seja, 9,007,199,254,740,991.

Comparando:

- 9007199254740991
- 36428971654192132

Tente usar [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt):

```
BigInt("36428971654192132");
```